# jquery to change the text value based on current text in a td

Tags: jquery

The scenario is: I have few `td`s and each `td` holds a different text. I'm binding a click event to the `td`s through a common selector.

When i click on the `td`, a dropdown will appear and the text in the `p` tag inside the `td` will change to "opened". When i click on the same `td` again (which will contain the text "opened"), the drop down will hide and the text will change back to the original value.

I believe we need to get the value of the text in some global variable or do you have any other ideas to achieve it?.

The structure is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#timeofday p").bind('click',function(event){
var read_txt= $(this).text();
$(this).text($(this).text() == 'opened' ? 'Click me' : 'Opened');
if(read_txt=='CLOSE')
{
$(this).parent().find(" > .dropdown").hide();

}
else
{
    $("#timeofday .dropdown").not(this).slideUp();
    $("#timeofday p").not(this).text($("#timeofday p").text('Click me') ); 
    $(this).parent().find(" > .dropdown").slideToggle();    

}   
});
```

The html is as follows:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td  id="timeofday" class="avbltyltblue">
<p>Click me</p>
<div id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
<div style="padding:10px 0"><button class="up" style="width:100px">UP</button></div>

<ul class="tlist">
<li>1:00PM</li>
<li>2:00PM</li>
<li>3:00PM</li>
<li>4:00PM</li>
<li>5:00PM</li>
<li>6:00PM</li>
<li>7:00PM</li>
<li>8:00PM</li>
<li>9:00PM</li>
<li>10:00PM</li>
</ul>

<div style="padding:10px 0"><button class="down" style="width:100px">DOWN</button></div>
</div>
</td>
<td  id="timeofday" class="avbltyltblue">
<p>test this</p>

<div id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
<div style="padding:10px 0"><button class="up" style="width:100px">UP</button></div>

<ul class="tlist">
<li>1:00PM</li>
<li>2:00PM</li>
<li>3:00PM</li>
<li>4:00PM</li>
<li>5:00PM</li>
<li>6:00PM</li>
<li>7:00PM</li>
<li>8:00PM</li>
<li>9:00PM</li>
<li>10:00PM</li>
</ul>

<div style="padding:10px 0"><button class="down" style="width:100px">DOWN</button></div>
</div>
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td  id="timeofday" class="avbltyltblue" style="z-index:1">
<p>CLick again</p>
<div id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
<div  style="padding:10px 0"><button class="up" style="width:100px">UP</button></div>

<ul class="tlist">
<li>1:00PM</li>
<li>2:00PM</li>
<li>3:00PM</li>
<li>4:00PM</li>
<li>5:00PM</li>
<li>6:00PM</li>
<li>7:00PM</li>
<li>8:00PM</li>
<li>9:00PM</li>
<li>10:00PM</li>
</ul>

<div style="padding:10px 0"><button class="down" style="width:100px">DOWN</button></div>
</div>
</td>
<td  id="timeofday" class="avbltyltblue">
<p>mouse event</p>

<div id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
<div style="padding:10px 0"><button class="up" style="width:100px">UP</button></div>

<ul class="tlist">
<li>1:00PM</li>
<li>2:00PM</li>
<li>3:00PM</li>
<li>4:00PM</li>
<li>5:00PM</li>
<li>6:00PM</li>
<li>7:00PM</li>
<li>8:00PM</li>
<li>9:00PM</li>
<li>10:00PM</li>
</ul>

<div style="padding:10px 0"><button class="down" style="width:100px">DOWN</button></div>
</div>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

In short, if I click on the "Click me" the dropdown will appear, and when I click on it again the text should revert to the original value and the dropdown should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to set a data attribute on the element to store the original text on click, then set it back by calling for that attribute.

```
$(this).data( 'original-text', $(this).text() ); // store original text

$(this).data( 'original-text' ); // retrieve original text
```

Comment: what is original-text supposed to be? how do i have to use the data function ??

Comment: 'original-text' is just an identifier, think of it as a variable name - it can be anything you want. Check out the jQuery .data() api http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to `.each()` through every one of the `p`aragraphs and save the text value in a variable:

```
$('#some p').each(function () {
    var p = $(this);
    var oldText = p.text();
    var open = false;

    p.click(function () {
        if (open) {
            p.text(oldText);
            dropDown.hide();
            open = false;
        }
        else {
            p.text('CLOSE');
            dropDown.show();
            open = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Unfinished pseudo-code but hopefully it helps.